# Move custom master page and site contents from on-premise to online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage

I have used custom master page in my SharePoint site and included scripts and CSS from Style Library in on-premise. Now i want to move my scripts, CSS and custom master page to SharePoint Online site. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 - Do it manually

Option 2 - Use Office 365 migration service
https://blogs.office.com/2015/09/16/office-365-import-service-migration-to-sharepoint-online-and-onedrive-for-business-just-became-easier/

Below points needs to be considered.

1. What is size of data(site contents, list/libraries? Depending on size you can do it either manually or via import service
2. Do you need to move permissions also ? This needs to be done manually only.
3. Is windows active directory setup or users already migrated to SP online ?

You should read below links to understand the migration process and what is best suitable to you.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Migrate-to-SharePoint-Online-d8c6ce52-f8a2-4661-97f7-45e49351bdb9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this thread having suggested solutions, might helps you to get in more detailed about how you can migrate custom farm solutions, custom master pages, page layouts, CSS in SharePoint on premises be migrated to SharePoint online Office 365 - [migrate custom master page, CSS to SharePoint online](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/e133f45f-727c-4528-9a93-695f75b13490/can-custom-farm-solutions-custom-master-pages-page-layouts-css-in-sharepoint-2010-be-migrated-to?forum=onlineservicessharepoint).

Hope this helps!